# Angular send User IP in a post request

Tags: angularjs

How can i get the user IP and send it in a post request?

```
.controller('LinkCtrl', function($scope, $http){

    $http.get("http://ipinfo.io").then(function(response){
        $scope.userIp = response.data
    })

    $scope.onClickLink = function($event){
        $http.post('http://localhost:7000/api/message', 
            {
                ip: userIp.ip
            })
    }    
})
```

My attempt sais : ReferenceError: userIp is not defined

Comment: `ip: $scope.userIp.ip`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot `$scope` before the variable name, you added an Ip in the scpe variable and used it without scope. so the error.

```
.controller('LinkCtrl', function($scope, $http){

    $http.get("http://ipinfo.io").then(function(response){
        $scope.userIp = response.data
    })

    $scope.onClickLink = function($event){
        $http.post('http://localhost:7000/api/message', 
            {
                ip: $scope.userIp.ip
            })
    }    
})
```

Comment: Thanks. I think i need a brake :D

Comment: :), it happens. keep going. you can accept my answer if you find it useful.